# Implement own transaction management by removing ejb

Tags: ejb

I have old ejb transaction management implemented in CMP. I need to remove this EJBs and build custom transaction management. I can't use spring for this. So please suggest me how to custom implement the transaction management which supports NotSupported, Required, RequiresNew

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately you haven't told us enough about the problem and what you've tried, resulting in a very broad question, and to answer it we'd have to write a tutorial which is off-topic.

Comment: As the question stated. I am planning to remove the ejb implementation. Need some approach for the underlaying system to work as per the ejb logic. like session management which has support for the NotSupported, Required, RequiresNew.  Hope this helps

Comment: removing ejb does not mean you need to implement Tx management. Declarative Tx management is one benefit of EE containers I would not implement this. You might use CDI @Transactional annotations. In any case you should be more specific what the use case is

Comment: What is your target in terms of JavaEE spec. version and application server?

Comment: Thanks for inputs. I am going to use openejb.